# Speed up python list search (Nested for loops)

Tags: python, loops, optimization

I'm currently working on moving some excel worksheets over to python automation, and have come across a speed issue.

I have a list of lists containing around 10.000 lists each with 20 or so columns. I also have a list of account numbers (100.000 numbers)

I wish to iterate over my list of lists and then pick out values from the list, if the account number in the lists matches one in the account list.

By running this code, i am able to get my desired result, however it is painfully slow.

```
calc = 0
for row in listOfLists:
    if row[1] in Accounts:
        calc += row[8]
```

Any ideas on how to optimize for speed?

Comment: Have you tried a list comprehension?

Comment: @thefourtheye Why do you expect a list comprehension to help in this case?

Comment: actually what he wants is a reduced version of it @thefourtheye

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make `Accounts` a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets). The contains check is [`O(1)` for sets, but `O(N)` for lists](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity). Your entire process' time complexity will be reduced from `O(M*N)` to `O(M+N)`. You can further use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) with a conditional [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```
account_set = set(Accounts)
calc = sum(row[8] for row in listOfLists if row[1] in account_set)
```

Comment: was about tu use sum, that answer is just perfect!

Answer (score 2):

A functional approach of this, using the `set` over `Accounts` as @schwobaseggle answered:

```
account_set = set(Accounts)
calc = reduce(lambda row: row[8] if row[1] in account_set else 0, listOfLists , 0)
```